# ghostscript conversion not creating output file when run in local environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, ghostscript

I am trying to run a simple script to convert a PDF --> PNG using gs package. The code runs successfully runs when deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions but I test it locally using the `firebase functions:shell` command it appears to run w/o error but the output file (the .png) is missing and I get the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/sr/pjwr5d0s75bgzvx4xgcdcylw0000gp/T/*****/-***********.png'

The path is correct, but the .png file is missing but the pdf is there and gs outputted no errors. I even tried changing the path from `os.tmpdir()` to a specific path on my desktop (Mac) and it still failed to create the png file.

The same code when deployed to firebase runs fine.

Here is my gs code (I have ommitted the CF code and invocation code):

```
//============== Ghostscript
    //Conver PDF -> PNG
    console.log('gs - starting');
    gs()
        .batch()
        .nopause()
        .option('-r' + 50 * 2)
        .option('-dDownScaleFactor=2')
        .executablePath('lambda-ghostscript/bin/./gs')
        // .device('png16m')
        .device('pngalpha')
        .output(outputPath)
        .input(pdfPath)
        .exec(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('gs executed w/o error');            
                console.log('stdout',stdout);            
                console.log('stderr',stderr);
                console.log('output saved to: ', outputPath);
                resolve(outputPath);
            } else {
                console.log('gs error:', err);
                reject();
            }
        });
})
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work locally but does when deployed. My path input is correct and the output is `path.join(os.tmpdir(), '****.png')`;

**Edit** Output from GS in console:

```
>  gs executed w/o error
>  stdout
>  stderr
>  output saved to:  /var/folders/sr/pjwr5d0s75bgzvx4xgcdcylw0000gp/T/*******/*********.png
```

Comment: When you say 'gs outputted no errors' what exact messages did you get back from Ghostscript via stdout and stderr ? What is the exact Ghostscript command line you are using ? (I can't figure ot out from the code), Can you post the PDF file you are using as input, so we can test that too please.

Comment: See my edit, I included the outputs from gs but as you can see, no errors

Comment: @KenS as I mentioned, it works fine when I run it on the cloud, but doesn't when I use the local firebase emulator. So it might not even be a bug with `gs`. I just can't figure out why everything appears to have worked except the file is missing.

Comment: That is not the Ghostscript output, there's no greeting and nothing that looks even remotely like the kind of output I'd expect. The most likely reason for no file being output is that there's 'something wrong' with the input file or a path or configuration problem, the stderr or stdout from Ghostscript should contain some information about the problem. Always assuming that the problem isn't the fact that you don't have a local copy of Ghostscript installed of course :-)

Comment: I'm thinking it must be the latter. How do I install a local copy of gs?

Comment: Well, that depends on your operating system, really. The Ghostscript website has binary installers for Linux and Windows (https://www.ghostscript.com/download.html). The Linux binary may or may not work on your system, it depends on your Linux. So, you can build from source by checking out the code either from Github (https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases) or the Ghostscript Git repository (http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=summary). Finally you couuld get the Ghostscript package using your choice of package manager. Most distros have one.

Comment: I'm on Mac. Currently using this compiled version because it works with AWS/Firebase. https://github.com/sina-masnadi/lambda-ghostscript 

The folder is in my local directory, and I'm pointing gs to it so it should work locally (and it does when deployed).

Comment: If you are putting that on a device open to the internet you need to be using a version **much** more up to date. You should be using at least 9.26, preferably 9.27. We don't supply any binaries for Mac at all. I'm not sure what you mean by 'pointing gs to it', that is Ghostscript surely ? Perhaps you mean you are pointing your JavaScript to it wherever you installed that ? Presuming Ghostscript works from the terminal (you haven't said) then I can't offer any more suggestions, it must be a configuration thing of some kind.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help and yes I did mean pointing my js invocation to ghostscript.